# Create Angular 2 component library without inline styles

Tags: angular, npm, libraries

I red [this](http://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-create-an-angular-2-library-and-how-to-consume-it-jspm-vs-webpack/) article about creating Angular 2 component library, and it uses inline styles. Is there a way to create a lib without inline styles in Angular 2?

Also I saw [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-angular2-library), but there is no word about styles, css.

My problem is, I want to create a complex component with multiple components in it and I use SASS also.

Comment: What do you mean *"without inline styles"*? Do you mean without styles, or with styles that aren't inline? I'd imagine you could follow the same workflow and use `templateUrl` and `styleUrls` with a similar outcome.

Comment: hi have you tired with webpack and require?

Comment: @jonrshape I mean with styles that aren't inline

Comment: Please provide information about the actual problem you are trying to solve. Why don't you want inline styles?

Comment: It's possible that they just used inline templates/styles to simplify the examples - did you *try* using URLs instead in the same workflow?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Another possible reason to completely avoid inline styles could be an aggressive [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy).

Comment: No, I want to copy the template and CSS files into the compiled lib with Grunt, but I also have to edit the references to SCSS to be CSS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that when you compile your npm package the styles templates must be inline because when you load it as a npm package you won't be able to achieve the template/css path inside node_modules.

The Angular Material 2 team used the follow gulp task to inline the css and template in its components:

They have created [this task](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/scripts/release/inline-resources.js) file that

1. Get external CSS and put inline;
2. Get external Html and put inline;
3. Removes the module.id from components;

Finally, in the build process they call this task [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/tools/gulp/tasks/components.ts#L125).

#### My approach of doing this:

1. Install `gulp`, `gulp-angular-embed-templates`, `gulp-inline-ng2-styles`.
2. Create a file called `gulpfile.js` at the root of your app
3. add the following code to your `gulpfile`:

   ```
   var gulp = require('gulp');
   var embedTemplates = require('gulp-angular-embed-templates');
   var inlineNg2Styles = require('gulp-inline-ng2-styles');

   gulp.task('js:build', function () {
     gulp.src('src/*.ts') // also can use *.js files
       .pipe(embedTemplates({sourceType:'ts'}))
       .pipe(inlineNg2Styles({ base: '/src' }))
       .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
   });
   ```
4. run `gulp js:build`;
5. run `npm run build`;

After that you will have a dist folder with a component containing your styles and template inline.

#### First answer (Does not solve the problem)

Just use `styleUrls` instead `styles`. Also works for template, just use `templateUrl` instead `template`:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'hello-world',
    styleUrls: ['./hello-world.component.scss'], // HERE (OR CSS)
    templateUrl: './hello-world.component.html', // THE SAME FOR TEMPLATE
})
export class HelloWorld {
    ...
}
```

Don't forget to create the new files with the styles and template (`./hello-world.component.scss` and `./hello-world.component.html`).

Comment: By creating `.html` and `.scss` you mean to copy from the source?

Comment: Yes. Remove from component declaration and put ir inside the respective files... like `/app/hello-world/hello-world.component.html`and `/app/hello-world/hello-world.component.css`

Comment: I don't know if you understand, I want to create a library, that I can use in an other project

Comment: I did. When you load this component in another one, the styles are loaded too based on `styleUrls`. What happens when you change the inline style to an external one?

Comment: I'm enjoying your question to build a npm module so I can tell you for sure. As soon as I end this I'll let you know and give you the source.

Comment: The link to the Angular team's file is broken. Is there another place to look at that?

Answer (score 2):

I use sass for all my components. If you use Webpack install `sass-loader` add:

```
loaders: [
             {
                 test: /\.scss$/,
                 exclude: /node_modules/,
                 loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
              }
         ],
```

and then in your component specify your components scss file

```
@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    templateUrl: './test.template.html',
    styleUrls: ['./test.styles.scss']
})
```

Then you can use sass external files for all your components.

Also if you need some global styles or want import a theme add this to your top level component. This is good for adding bootstrap to your app or some global styles your components might need to share:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    templateUrl: './app.template.html',
    styleUrls: [
        '../assets/scss/bootstrap.scss',
        './app.style.scss'
    ]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use external HTML templates and CSS styles (or even SCSS styles) you might inline them first before NGC compilation by using Gulp and 'gulp-inline-ng2-template' plugin.

[image: Angular library build workflow with external SCSS and HTML tempaltes]

Here is how you npm scripts may look like in **package.json**:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "build:esm": "gulp inline-templates && npm run ngcompile",
    "ngcompile": "node_modules/.bin/ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json",
    ...
  }
}
```

Then **gulpfile.js** would look like.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('node-sass');
const inlineTemplates = require('gulp-inline-ng2-template');

/**
 * Inline templates configuration.
 * @see  https://github.com/ludohenin/gulp-inline-ng2-template
 */
const INLINE_TEMPLATES = {
  SRC: './src/**/*.ts',
  DIST: './tmp/src-inlined',
  CONFIG: {
    base: '/src',
    target: 'es6',
    useRelativePaths: true,
    styleProcessor: compileSass
  }
};

/**
 * Inline external HTML and SCSS templates into Angular component files.
 * @see: https://github.com/ludohenin/gulp-inline-ng2-template
 */
gulp.task('inline-templates', () => {
  return gulp.src(INLINE_TEMPLATES.SRC)
    .pipe(inlineTemplates(INLINE_TEMPLATES.CONFIG))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(INLINE_TEMPLATES.DIST));
});


/**
 * Compile SASS to CSS.
 * @see https://github.com/ludohenin/gulp-inline-ng2-template
 * @see https://github.com/sass/node-sass
 */
function compileSass(path, ext, file, callback) {
  let compiledCss = sass.renderSync({
    data: file,
    outputStyle: 'compressed',
  });
  callback(null, compiledCss.css);
}
```

This approach is utilized by [angular-library-seed](https://github.com/trekhleb/angular-library-seed). You may look there for full integration example.